# php not reading the right number of spaces, condenses 1+ into 1

Tags: php, spaces

I am reading log files that have been compressed with gzip in a php script. Nothing is missing from the text, but all of the instances of multiple spaces have been reduced to a single space.

Here is an example of the output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Exit Status : 1 |
```

When it should have looked like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Exit Status : 1                                                             |
```

Here is the relevant part of the script I think:

```
$lines = gzfile("$filename.gz");

# If the file is empty, say that to be more user friendly
if($lines == "") {
    echo "File empty";
} else {
    echo "<div style=\"font-family:courier new;font-size:12pt\">";
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        echo nl2br($line);
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

I also tried it without nl2br, just as a test, and the spaces were still reduced to one. The file is intact as I viewed it with zcat in a terminal just to be sure something hadn't actually written the file incorrectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you viewing the source code or the rendered page? if the source code looks fine, and your rendered page does not, try using the <pre> tags and a fixed width font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're outputing HTML markup, I presume you're viewing the output of your PHP script in a web browser. If this is the case, you're encouring a quirk of HTML, not PHP. Specifically, web browsers render any expanse of whitespace as one space. It's how HTML works.

To view all the spaces, you need to wrap the output in `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: That fixed the spacing issue, but now there are extra newlines. Is that normal? I tried this:echo "<pre style=\"display:inline;margin:0px;padding=0px\">"; but that didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. Using nl2br inside of a <pre> block was inserting another newline. Thanks so much for the help!